# Undefined member function error at num_row(). in codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

Error at num_rows() as undefined member function. For dispalying data in descending order in codeigniter Framework.
I tried this code:

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('albums');
    $result = $this->db->order_by('album_id', 'desc');
    //$result = $this->db->get('albums');
    if($result->num_rows()  > 0)
    {
        return $result;
    }
```

For fetching and displaying rows in descending order i used the above code. But i am getting the following error at `num_rows() as undefined function`. How do I print it in descending order?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to execute `get()` before getting the count of rows.

So your Code should look like this,

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('albums');
$this->db->order_by('album_id', 'desc');
$result = $this->db->get(); // add this line
if($result->num_rows()  > 0)
{
    return $result;
}
```

`get()` function runs the selection query.

Comment: I have assign two times?

Comment: No you don't need to assign it two times, I've updated the code.

Comment: Yes that's working perfectly. thank you @Alok patel.

Comment: how do i follow you here?

Comment: Just click on the check mark beside my answer to select it.

Comment: and for any website, is it compulsory to have the javascript or jquery or ajax, actually i have almost completed one website but never wrote any of these javascript or jquery or ajax. is that oaky?

Comment: Yeah it not necessary to use jQuery or AJAX until and unless you need it.

Comment: Please avoid comments for asking questions. You can post questions for that.

Answer (score 1):

Change you'r code to :

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('albums');
$result = $this->db->order_by('album_id', 'desc');
$result = $this->db->get('albums')->row();
if($result->num_rows()  > 0)
{
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
$this ->db->select('*');
$this ->db->from('albums');
$this->db->order_by('album_id', 'desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    return $query->result();
}
```

If you need help hit me up :)

**EDIT**

You need

```
$query->result();
```

To return it as an object, but you you like you can use

```
$query->result_array();
```

To return it as array, don't just return $query as it is :)